# Why am I losing type information?

Tags: java, iterator, type-erasure, generics

I have found something interesting to happen with Maps, rawtypes and generics. Following code:

```
static {
          Map map = new HashMap ();
          Set <Map.Entry> set = map.entrySet ();
          for (Map.Entry entry : set) {} // fine 
          for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {} // compilation error
}
```

I am getting a compilation error about a Type incompatibility, namely: "Object cannot be cast to Entry".

[Ideone for convenience](http://ideone.com/R8sK7L)

Why is the iterator over `entrySet()` losing the type information if there's no variable storing it again?

The rawtypes shouldn't affect the type so that `Map.Entry` suddenly is an Object. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: `Set <Map.Entry> set = map.entrySet ();` is an "unchecked assignment" which is allowed. That is what allows the first iterator to work.
You can achive the same result by making the cast explicit in the second case:`for(Map.Entry entry : (Set<Map.Entry>)map.entrySet()) { }`

Comment: The very basic rule to follow is: never use raw types. They are rather easy to avoid (usually replaced with a wildcard parameter, i.e. `Set` turns into `Set<?>`) and the only reason for their existence is backwards compatibility with pre-generics code.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, agreed, but I assume this is a mostly academic question. edit: Ok, so it's _not_ academic, but it is a fun question anyhow.

Comment: @Joachim right. This doesn't help when maintaining legacy code from pre generics times and it's not really constructive to the question in any way...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example makes it look like you have type information that  you never had. You have written:

```
Map map = new HashMap ();
Set <Map.Entry> set = map.entrySet();
for (Map.Entry entry : set) {} // fine 
for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {} // compilation error
```

But `map.entrySet()` is returning `Set`, not `Set <Map.Entry>`. You've performed an unchecked assignment which "adds" type information.

In the second for loop, we don't know what's inside the `Set`, so we can't iterate over `Set <Map.Entry>` without an explicit cast.

For example, compare the original example to this one where we don't "add" type information with the unchecked assignment.

```
Map map = new HashMap();
Set set = map.entrySet();
for (Map.Entry entry : set) {
} // Object cannot be cast to Entry
for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
} // Object cannot be cast to Entry
```

In this case, both for loops produce a compilation error.

This behaviour is documented in the Java Language Specification, section 4.8:

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), **instance method** (§8.8, §9.4), or
>   non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from
>   its superclasses or superinterfaces is the erasure of its type in the
>   generic declaration corresponding to C. The type of a static member of
>   a raw type C is the same as its type in the generic declaration
>   corresponding to C.

Comment: "But map.entrySet() is returning Set, not Set <Map.Entry>." -> This seems to contradict with the documentation, which explicitly states that the return type of `entrySet()` is `Set<Entry>`.

Comment: @Unihedro: the difference is that `map` has a raw type, which means that all generic information will be ignored when you call a method on it. So `map.entrySet()` indeed returns a `Set` and not a `Set<Map.Entry>`.

Comment: @Unihedro, you can only refer to `Map.Entry` if you've declared the generic types in the declaration. By using rawtypes you've changed the method contract. The Javadoc for the generic classes doesn't mention that they return rawtypes if the type information is not given (e.g. [List.subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)), but that is how they are designed.

Comment: This is also referred to in [4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6): *"The return type of a method and the type parameters of a generic method or constructor also undergo erasure if the method or constructor's signature is erased."*.

Answer (score 4):

I think the short answer is that Java allows "unchecked cast" in some situations but not others. Dealing with raw types (Generic types without a specified type) is one of these instances.

Keep in mind that `for (Map.Entry entry : set)` is equivalent to:

```
Iterator it = set.iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    Map.Entry entry = it.next();
}
```

The assignment:

```
Set set = map.entrySet();
```

is allowed and will not generate any warning, as you are not introducing any new type, but in the `for` loop `it.next()` will return type `Object` and you will get compiler exception if you assign it without an explicit cast.

The assignment:

```
Set <Map.Entry> set = map.entrySet();
```

is allowed but will generate an "unchecked cast" warning because of the explicit type `Map.Entry` and in the `for` loop `it.next()` will return type `Map.Entry` and the assignment will work fine.

You can put the explicit cast in the for loop like this:

```
for(Map.Entry entry : (Set<Map.Entry>) map.entrySet())
```